# how to print more than one rows through PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

How to write a procedure where user will give department number, and the procedure will show the list of those employees who are working in that department.

My procedure:

```
create or replace procedure p1(
  dno in number,
  name out varchar2 )
is 
begin 
 select ename 
   into name 
   from emp 
  where deptno=dno;
end;
```

PLSQL:

```
declare
   dno emp.deptno%type:=:dept;
   name emp.ename%type;
begin
  p1(dno,name );
  dbms_output.put_line(name);
end;
```

But this is showing an error:

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
```

How can I print multiple values through procedure?

Comment: you need to use a cursor.

Comment: I tried  but I don't know exact way to use cursor in procedure.

Comment: All that you need to know: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html Read and try then, if you still don't get it, come back! :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code, but you seen to call the procedure `p1(dno,name );` and insert name in it. 
 
But `name` can only be output becuase of the `OUT`, you need to use `IN OUT` in your procedure at least.

Comment: In this procedure 
I want that user will give the dept no.
and the procedure will show the name of all employees who are working under this dept.
so `IN OUT` is not needed here.
I need to use cursor.
but I don't know the exact way to use cursor in procedure :)